# Add parts to absolute path

Tags: javascript, html

I have given absolute path like `src="/test.png"` all across the application. I have added my base url like `href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/"` in HTML head section. But since I have used absolute path instead of relative in HTML, the part `"/images/"` in base url I have given is not appending to the url of the image.

Instead of coming like:

```
src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/test.png"
                              ^^^^^^
```

it is coming like:

```
src="http://www.w3schools.com/test.png".
```

Is there anyway I can achieve the way I want without going through each and every pages and changing absolute path to relative?

Comment: Just give `src="test.png"`

Comment: You have completely misunderstood how "base urls" work, and what the beginning `/` does...

Comment: simple answer to the actual question is, you need to edit every page - or add some code to some javascript that is loaded in every page to "fix" the path retrospectively

Comment: is it only `<image>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
src="test.png"
```

Without `/` because `/` will make it refer to root.

Comment: So to answer the actual question, that would be, "there is no way to achieve what you want without going through each and every pages and changing absolute path to relative" :p

Comment: Is there any other solution now besides removing "/" ?? like from javascript? It will be really tedious to go thoroughly through all the pages.

Comment: if you have a js file that is loaded in every page, then you can retrospectively fix this problem - the result may not be pretty, but it should be simples

Comment: I would suggest instead of using js to remove `/` from src each time, prefer find and relace in your text editor. :) May sound the boring way but it will be beneficial in long run

Comment: I would suggest the js fix only as a quick **interim** fix - only if on a **tight** time schedule

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I am actually looking for a quick interim fix for now so was trying to find some js solution which I am not able to find.

Comment: @JaromandaX : agree with you. not  permanent but will be quick interim fix,

Comment: @Chyangba : is it only with image tag?

Comment: In anchor tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

To include the parent's URL(`http://www.w3schools.com/images/`), use this:

```
src= "./test.png"
```

It will then result in

```
src = "http://www.w3schools.com/images/test.png"
```